# Spring Security display data on every page

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to show full name on every page. I am using spring security. But I am only able to display username. Here is the code.

```
public ModelAndView indexController(ModelMap model)
{
     User user = (User)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
     model.addAttribute("fullname", user.getUsername());

     return new ModelAndView("index", model);

}
```

I can only display username i.e. email here. How can I get fullname to display on every page.

Comment: Based on the username, fetch the extended info of user from db and add them to your model

Comment: probably that `user.getUsername()` returns a username, what do you think?

Comment: I want to get firstname + lastname to be saved in `User` predefined class, so that I can access it.

Comment: You should extend the spring's `User` class and then during authentication, create an instance from this class and put it into the `SecurityContextHolder`.

Comment: Well `User` class only contains usename, where do you store firstname and lastname?

Comment: @AliDehghani, Thanks for your suggestion. It worked. You should have write it answer!

Comment: You can simply query the `Users` table and put the name in to the session. So that you have access in all pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extend spring's `User` class or implement the `UserDetails` interface in one of your own entities and put an instance of that entity in the `SecurityContextHolder` after successful authentication. Suppose, you a have `User` entity (not to be confused with spring's `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User`), then you can implement the `UserDetails` interface like following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Set<String> roles = new HashSet<>();

    public User() {}

    public User(String username, String password, Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.roles = authorities.stream().map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    @Id
    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "roles")
    public Set<String> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<String> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    @Override
    @Transient
    public Collection<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return roles.stream().map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    @Transient
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    @Transient
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    @Transient
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    @Transient
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then you can define a `UserDetailsService` to search users based on the `username` and return an instance of the `User` entity, if possible. Something like following:

```
@Override
@Autowired
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .userDetailsService(username -> {
                User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

                if (user == null) throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid user");

                return user;
            });
}
```

Finally, when you're using `SecurityContextHoler`, you can cast the principal to your `User` entity which has the `firstName` and `lastName` attributes:

```
User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
model.addAttribute("fullname", user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName());
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Although I already did extending `User` class as you suggested!